# State-of-the-art presentation package in LaTeX (as of 2015)?

Tags: beamer, presentations

Haven't made any presentation in LaTeX for a while. Is Beamer still the best choice? Any new stuffs available?

Comment: Best choice is IMHO still `beamer`.

Comment: I have to vote for *opinion-based* since this is not going to be helpful for others even six months later if a new thing pops up a month later. Please come to the chat room for such questions.

Comment: @JuriRobl Thx, much appreciated. I used to "animate" and "media9" inside Beamer, terrible experience....

Comment: @percusse whatever you say man. Play power is what people do these days.

Comment: @TroyWoo I used both packages without any problems, other than a slightly longer time to load the frame. Of course you have to pick a viewer which supports the added media elements.

Comment: Yes I'm known for being a vote-maniac here. I try to close everything.

Comment: @JuriRobl Yes, I succeeded finally, but the time spent is just too much.

Comment: @percusse very funny...

Comment: @TroyWoo: Percusse is well known here for _not_ abusing of powers the system provides (have a look to [Reviewers; what do you eat for breakfast?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4622/reviewers-what-do-you-eat-for-breakfast)). I also think this question is _opinion-based_, as both of the questions you asked (_Is Beamer still the best choice?_ and _Any new stuffs available?_) can lead to open discussion. Please try to narrow the scope of the question to get reasonable answers.

Comment: Although the question is closed already I want to add, that it's always a personal choice which tools/packages are used, regardless `state of the art` or not. So it's opionion-based

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Either way it is ok with me. I got what information I needed. And abuse of power is everywhere. It is just a matter of time we realize it.